# Copy keys from on Dictionary to another Dictionary

Tags: c#

Using C# 7 I have two dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<String, String> sources = service.GetSources();

Dictionary<String, List<Object>> targets;
```

I need to copy all keys from sources to targets.

For each new target the value will be new `List<Object>`, so just initialize it.

Can this be done without a foreach loop?

Comment: This is most likely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  There is no reason to do this.

Comment: `souces.Keys.ToList().ForEach(x => targets.Add(x, new List<object>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var targets = source.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => new List<object>());
```